# Compelx plane : Draw each step of $z$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1=2+i$, $z_2=2$, $z_3=1-\frac{i}{2}$ and $z_4=\frac{i}{3}$.

Draw these numbers in the complex plane.

Calculate $z=\overline{(z_2\cdot z_1+z_3)\cdot z_4}$ and do each step also graphically.

$$$$

As for the second part, to draw each step graphically do we just calculate for example $z_2\cdot z_1$ and then we draw that in the complex plane? Or is it meant to do the calculations on the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would draw $z_2\cdot z_1$  and label it on the graph as such, and then do the same for each step of the rest of the calculation.

It's a rather tedious procedure, but it is good for understanding the graphical impact of complex transformations.

Comment: Ok! So we get: https://ibb.co/Cv7CnN5 right?

Comment: Perfect. Nicely done.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)